# Powershell invoke-command multihopping

Tags: powershell, networking, invoke-command

I have a question regarding multihopping in a windows environment.
Let's say I have a schedule running on Server A (Central Scheduler) which executes a command on Server B. This script contains a call to save files on a remote filer (UNC path, Server C). Hop 1 (from A to B) works well, hop 2 (from B to C) fails. 
I already tested to save the files locally on server B, that works flawlessly.
I think there's a problem with the second hop. I remember reading something like this on a forum a while ago, but can't remember a solution.
In detail, the command looks like this:

```
$session = New-PSSession -computer ComputerName    
$templatepath = "\\filerpath\"
Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock { powershell ovpmutil cfg pol dnl $Using:templatepath /p \BSH }
```

To clarify: Powershell gives me an "Access denied" when performing the second hop. I already enabled Credential delegation as described here: 
[Enabling Multihop Remoting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/04/enabling-multihop-remoting/)
Any help is appreciated.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) to add this information to it instead of commenting your own question.

Comment: I've had some issues with CredSSP previously. The answer in this post solved the issue for me: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/544e2da5-390d-411d-a730-1fceab18334d/network-access-when-using-invokecommand-or-enterpssession?forum=winserverpowershell
Specifically the part for the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a real pain in the backside if you ask me but here it is...

On the originating server (A):

```
Set-Item WSMAN:\localhost\client\auth\credssp -value $true
```

On the intermediate server (B):

```
Set-Item WSMAN:\localhost\client\auth\credssp -value $true
```

Open Group Policy editor on server A, navigate to:

> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Credentials Delegation

Enable these options:

- Allow delegating fresh credentials
- Allow delegating fresh credentials with NTLM-only server authentication

Both policies need to have server B added to the allowed list, wildcards are allowed. Note that if you use RDP from server A you'll also need to add `TERMSRV/*`

When running Invoke-Command from server A, include the `-Authentication CredSSP` param.

Note that if saving SecureStrings somewhere for the credential to connect to server C, you'll want to either use a fixed encryption (specify byte array) or plain  text and convert it.